# Programming a 'Check for updates' button to determine changes in a repository

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I have an application that is in very early development, and still consistently updates or fixing bugs. The program is designed to do a lot of my jobs auditing automatically and currently is being used by 5-7 people who heard of it through the grape vine.

I don't like constantly sending out emails asking to spread the word that an updates has rolled out, so I'd like to implement some sort of 'check for update' button. How would I go about doing something like this?

The button would simply check for a new version number in my release repository and let the user know if their version number is behind, is that the right route to go for this kind of action? Or is there a much easier path?

Comment: @JBentley I appreciate the response, I've never dealt with distributing my software before and never expected other people to use my application. I feel overwhelmed as I have not the slightest clue how to package my program into a binary download or package manager, do you have any links to learning how to do this?

Comment: This 'check for update' button could indeed be used to check the repository for changes, but when released, it could be used by the end users to check for app updates, no?

Comment: @JBentley: you do not have a package manager on Windows, at least any reliable where update can come handy.

Comment: @Gmercer015: which operating system are you using? Are you looking for a Qt solution with signals and slots?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'm aiming for a proper windows 7 release

Comment: @Gmercer015: could you please clarify why you need a checkbox? Wouldn't it be better to use QFileSystemWatcher and popup a notification automatically without even a checkbox interaction?

Comment: @JBentley: The point for the OP to avoid the announcement (and hence separate website, etc), and the feedback would come from within the application. None of your ideas would address that concern AFAICT.

Comment: @JBentley: 1) There is no reliable package manager available for Windows. 2) The whole point was to avoid website/announcement check outside the application. => Your comments were not relevant, I am afraid, because it was referring to package manager and/or website (explicit check like an announcement outside the application).

Comment: @JBentley: The OP has never mentioned VCS. That seems to be only coming from you. It is even mentioned that it is a "release repository". That is not any different to binary package repositories on Linux for various distributions, etc. It is a mirror if you like. I am afraid you got into trouble with your own interpretation. What the OP wants looks perfectly reasonable to me. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp I see now that there has been a terminology confusion on my part, so I have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to even avoid using a checkbox for this, and just fully automate the process by using [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QFileSystemWatcher.html).

You would need to add the desired path for watching first:

> [bool QFileSystemWatcher::addPath(const QString & path)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#addPath)
>
> Adds path to the file system watcher if path exists. The path is not added if it does not exist, or if it is already being monitored by the file system watcher.
>
> If path specifies a directory, the directoryChanged() signal will be emitted when path is modified or removed from disk; otherwise the fileChanged() signal is emitted when path is modified, renamed or removed.
>
> If the watch was successful, true is returned.
>
> Reasons for a watch failure are generally system-dependent, but may include the resource not existing, access failures, or the total watch count limit, if the platform has one.
>
> Note: There may be a system dependent limit to the number of files and directories that can be monitored simultaneously. If this limit is been reached, path will not be monitored, and false is returned.

You would be connected to the [following signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged):

> void QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged(const QString & path) [signal]
>
> This signal is emitted when the file at the specified path is modified, renamed or removed from disk.

The handler slot could then just bring up some notification to the user automatically, even without an explicit checkbox.

Putting all this into practice, I would write something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(myFileSystemWatcherPointer, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString &)), SLOT(handleFileChanged(const QString &)));
    myFileSystemWatcherPoiner->addPath(myFilePath);
}

MyClass::handleFileChanged(const QString &file)
{
    if (file == desiredFile)
        showUpdatePopUp();
}
```